# How to override unit_amount_in_cents for subscribe?

Tags: recurly

I am using recurly json based api to make subscribe call but looks like the card is always being charged for what the plan value is. I am trying to change unit value for the plan by sending unit_amount_in_cents in subscription object but its not working.

Here are the call info:

End point: `https://api.recurly.com/jsonp/:subdomain:/subscribe?callback=cbFunc`

Data:

```
subscription[plan_code]:<plan code>
subscription[quantity]:1
subscription[currency]:USD
subscription[unit_amount_in_cents]:2
account: <Account object>
billing_info: <biling info object>
signature: <signature>
```

The problem is recurly is always charging what the plan value per unit is, instead of charging 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

Recurly.js v2 does not support the override of a subscription plan's default price.

Comment: But I think I am using recurly v1. Check the end point I am hitting.

Comment: It wouldn't be supported in v2 or previous versions.